# Eclipse Kepler in Ubuntu/Debian ==> CONTROL + C (copy) don’t work

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, keyboard, key

In my university we use Eclipse on PC under Linux (XFCE Desktop in Debian).

But CONTROL + C for COPY don’t work… Ctrl + V, Ctrl + X seems work but not Ctrl+C. We tried many things in Preferences > General > Keys > Binding on Ctrl + C but… nothing work.

Any idea ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by restoring default keys.
Preferences > General > Keys > Respore Defaults.
Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

XFCE4 probably has Ctrl+C bound to some other task. I don't remember exactly where, but you can check the key bindings for XFCE4.

Comment: Make sure you have "In Dialogs and Windows" selected for "Copy" in the General|Keys settings.

Comment: I post print screen of KEYS and ERROR Log but I don't see where is the problem

Comment: It looks like you have some user configured keys, including the copy. Can you scroll to the right and export your key bindings to a CSV file and post that here. And since you have a backup now, maybe you can restore them to default and see if that works.